# Akka.Net - Create a child actor through DI

Tags: akka.net

I'm looking for references on how to create a child actor through dependency injection. I've found this example I found in [this link](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/dependency-injection.html):

```
var actorProps = Context.DI().Props<MyActor>()
```

But I don't seem to have that extension method available (I'm currently using V1.4.18). In addition to that, The same link has this warning:

> There is currently still an extension method available for the actor Context. Context.DI().ActorOf<>. However this has been officially deprecated and will be removed in future versions.

So what is the new and correct way to create child actors via dependency injection?

Comment: (crickets chirping)

Answer (score 1):

https://petabridge.com/blog/akkadotnet-dependencyinjection/ - came out in January of this year and the documentation you linked to explains that the new module is `Akka.DependencyInjection`, which has all of the new methods for doing DI in Akka.NET: https://getakka.net/articles/actors/dependency-injection.html#integrating-with-microsoftextensionsdependencyinjection